# Error resulting in a 'jumping mesh' during mesh manipulation

Tags: modeling, mesh

Ive been having a problem recently that seems apparently quite random for which I have no solution. this has happened to me before on one occasion and it seems to be at random moments while modelling something I have an active mirror modifier on. for some reason, when attempting to manipulate a corner, line or face, the selected mesh part 'jumps' as shown in the photos below. I have no solution for this nor do I have a cause. I do not know what to look for so if there is already an answer to this topic/ problem could you please point me to it. as you can see, these pictures show the foot I'm modelling in 2 stages, as it is and after I mimipulate it. these 2 stages are one after the other. there is no actual room for development or movement. it 'jumps'. it seems random and I don't know what causes it or how to reverse it. any ideas?[image: .]

Comment: I'm pretty sure I know what the problem is. Can you provide a screenshot of your 3D viewport? Be sure that all the menus and buttons are visible...

Comment: i feel kind of stupid. I realised this issue is a result of the magnet icon at the screen base being turned on. all it needed was a bit of looking around. @matt

Comment: Yup, that's what I suspected ;-) These kinds of solutions are nice because once you figure it out, you'll look for it every time.